# Is there a way to get the emails of new YouTube subscribers? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, youtube, youtube-data-api

So as the title says.. ''Is there a way to get the emails of new YouTube subscribers? Python''

i am planning to build an emailing list wherein if a person subscribes to my youtube channel, i want to be able to automatically send them an email containing my latest blogs and video updates. so is there a way to do that? maybe using the youtube api? or external codes or websites?

i know that i could just ask them for their email addresses using a google form and link that  to a python script that sends emails using SMTP but i want to do it automatically when they subscribe to my youtube channel.

any help will help alot

thank you

Comment: You can get in trouble with GDPR. If your users aren't specifically signing up for such a marketing campaign, you can't do it. You can, however, send a welcome email but after that you need explicitly given consent.

Comment: thank you for informing me about GDPR.. so how could i send the welcome email?

Comment: For how, you the answers. A welcome email is not really an issue with GDPR since the user took explicit steps to trigger it. But if you store the email, or use to any porpose you must be upfront and clear about it. Like facebook is clear about it..... oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can use the youtube api. Simply call the api, and get whatsoever the element is, for new subscribers. Then, you can create a text and mail it to yourself.
For making it run all the time, you have to go to the terminal and keep it running...